# phonegap ios loading screen doesnt show

Tags: ios, cordova

I dragged the icons from an external folder first into the Iphone Deployment Info Section, then dragged the files (since they were shown at the root level of my www folder)to the icons and the splash section of the Resources Group. I also removed all the phonegap default images for the splashscreen and the icons. 
The Loading screen files come as .png and have the correct names and sizes after the [guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) (480x320 for normal, 960x640 for the retina).

While the app-icon shows immediately, the splash screen wont show on my device, an iphone 3 with ios 4.1 on it. The Iphone 3 still shows the phonegap default screen. Anyone knows ho to fix this?

I only have one test device but on the simulators, the correct loading screen is shown. I already cleaned the project and restarted xcode.

Comment: hi, have you replaced both the default splash screens?? default.png and default@2x.png

Comment: in this situation i can only suggest you to check with the resources coz that works with me fine. clean the project and check it once again.

Answer (score 1):

Run the 'Clean' command from the Product menu in Xcode.

After struggling with this for a while, this was finally the simple command that overrode Phonegap's default splash screen (assuming the images are setup and named correctly).